Is it good practice for my browser app to set the Accept-Language header?
My SPA has a language switcher. Right now changing the language will set the Accept-Language header to use in the next calls to my backend. This is serving my purpose but I'm wondering if that's considered good practice at all.
My understanding is the browser would set that header using the user's language preference if any. Do some browsers prevent overriding that header for example?

Using the Accept-Language header for this purpose is perfectly normal and compliant with HTTP specs. Especially if the user intentionally uses a language switcher to change the website's language. It is considered best practice to use the browser's initial language setting as the default value (before user has selected anything) for Accept-Language header though. I've not heard of browsers that don't allow you to override this setting.
